# How to stop infinity score loop in quiz app JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

when I click on the show result button it shows me the results in an alert but when I click again on the show result without refreshing the page the score adds to the last result also. like first I got 2 scores when I click on a result again it adds the current score with the last one.
it is a quiz app with 4 questions and 4 choices.
kindly help me how to clear the last score.

```
var score = 0;
function show() {
  correctAnswer1 = document.getElementById("q1_a2");

  questionAnswer1 = document.getElementById("q1_a3");
  questionAnswer1 = document.getElementById("q1_a4");
  questionAnswer1 = document.getElementById("q1_a1");

  if (correctAnswer1.checked == true) {
    score++;
    alert("Q1 correct answer");
  } else {
    alert("Q1 wrong answer");
  }

  correctAnswer2 = document.getElementById("q2_a3");

  questionAnswer2 = document.getElementById("q2_a2");
  questionAnswer2 = document.getElementById("q2_a4");
  questionAnswer2 = document.getElementById("q2_a1");

  if (correctAnswer2.checked == true) {
    score++;
    alert("Q2 correct answer");
  } else {
    alert("Q2 wrong answer");
  } 
  
  correctAnswer3 = document.getElementById("q4_a4");

  questionAnswer3 = document.getElementById("q4_a2");
  questionAnswer3 = document.getElementById("q4_a3");
  questionAnswer3 = document.getElementById("q4_a1");

  if (correctAnswer3.checked == true) {
    score++;
    alert("Q3 correct answer");
  } else {
    alert("Q3 wrong answer");
  }  
  correctAnswer4 = document.getElementById("q4_a4");

  questionAnswer4 = document.getElementById("q4_a2");
  questionAnswer4 = document.getElementById("q4_a3");
  questionAnswer4 = document.getElementById("q4_a1");

  if (correctAnswer4.checked == true) {
    score++;
    alert("Q4 correct answer");
  } else {
    alert("Q4 wrong answer");
  }
  alert("your score is: " + score)
}
```

Comment: Put `var score = 0` *inside* the function…!?

Comment: *"how to clear the last score"* - `score = 0`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after the alert function will be executed if an user clicks on "ok". If this happens you could set the score to 0 again.

```
...
alert("your score is: " + score)
score = 0
//  the code that you put here will be executed after the user clicks OK in the alert box
```